# Is a direct GPON ONT connection faster than through an ethernet ONT?

Tags: ethernet, fiber, sfp

If I have a GPON ISP, is it possible, and if possible, is it faster or better, to use a GPON ONT<->SFP adapter directly into a server rather than using a GPON ONT<->GigabitEthernet interface or router?

Or, how can you get the full 1.25 Gbps upstream, 2.5Gbps downstream available on the GPON to a server?

Comment: ONT-SFP vs. a free standing ONT makes no difference -- it's the same thing in a different package. Your rates are dictated by the OLT (i.e. ISP) -- the ONT will obey what it's told.

Comment: Assuming the ONT isn't being told to limit to 1gbps, will SFP still be the bottleneck?

Comment: The hypothetical question in you comment is really off-topic. From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "_you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: 'What if ______ happened?'_"

Comment: To rephrase it to match the main question, how about: "How can I get the full 1.25 gpbs upstream, 2.5gbps downstream available, assuming my ISP is not limiting the connection to 1gbps symmetric?"

Answer (score 1):

You are not likely to be able to terminate the fiber yourself. There are several variables for GPON and the session built on top, and the termination must match what is used in the ISP network.

Additionally, it wouldn't make a difference. The translation to copper does cause some additional latency - but in the magnitude of a few microseconds this doesn't have any impact.

Furthermore - as Ricky has pointed out - you can't increase your data rate above what your plan allows. The rate isn't limited in the ONT but further upstream.